# pagination with hash and parameters doesn't work

Tags: php, html, pagination

I have page with a URL like this:

```
http://***.com/profile/username#profile_favs
```

With my pagination it looks like this:

```
http://***.com/profile/username?s=0&p=1#profile_favs
```

The last example doesn't work.

Basically my pagination-function looks like this:

```
function Pagination($pages, $start, $display, $link_url="", $anchor="") {

echo '<div id="pagination">';

    $current_page = ($start / $display) + 1;

    $paginator_num = 5;
    $pages_display = 10;

    if ($current_page > $pages - $paginator_num) {
        $paginator_num = $pages_display - ($pages - $current_page);
    } elseif ($current_page < $paginator_num + 1) {
        $paginator_num = $pages_display - $current_page;
    } else {
        $paginator_num = 5;
    }

    $min = max($current_page - $paginator_num, 1); 
    $max = min($current_page + $paginator_num, $pages); 

    for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            echo '<div class="pagination_link">';
                echo '<a href="/'.$link_url.'?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . $anchor.'">' . $i . '</a>';
            echo '</div>';

        } else {
            echo '<div id="pagination_active" class="pagination_link">';
                echo $i . ' ';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }       

    echo '</div>';
}
```

And this is the part that calculates the pages (this part gets included right before my pagination-function):

```
<?php
$display = $display_num;

if (isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric ($_GET['p'])) {
    $pages = $_GET['p'];

} else {
    $total_results = $qr_num;

    if ($total_results > $display) {
        $pages = ceil ($total_results / $display);
    } else {
        $pages = 1;

    }
}

if (isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric ($_GET['s'])) {

    $start = $_GET['s'];

} else {
    $start = 0;
}



?>
```

Now my question is: Is there any workaround possible to get that pagination working with a URL mentioned above:

```
http://***.com/profile/username?s=0&p=1#profile_favs
```

Actually I'd prefer a solution without GET-parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use an AJAX call with the XMPHttpRequest Object to  fetch it without the get parameters.
2. Another thing you could do (if you are using Apache) is to look at mod_rewrite for urls.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the hints!:) I'll check it out ASAP!

Comment: With an AJAX-call it works!:) BTW: Although I'm using APACHE I don't have any experiences with .htaccess-files! So that mod_rewrite-thingy is something I would never use...so thanks for your help, buddy!:D

Comment: Glad to help @drpelz .. I havn't used it myself. But never be afraid to try (ofcourse do take proper precautions if its a live website lol ). :)